# How do I include an image (jpg) with a lambda function?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to write a lambda that puts a watermark on an image, then saves the result to S3.  I'm using the [Sharp library](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/) to do so.  I'm deploying with [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/).

I'm unsure how to 'include' the image with the lambda.  I'll be watermarking millions of images, so I want to avoid having to 'read' the image from S3 every time and I'd like to just have it be included in the lambda package.

```
let overlayResp;
    try {
        const overlayImg = await Sharp(sourceImage.Body)
        .composite([{input: './logos/white.png', gravity: 'southeast' }])
        .toFormat('jpeg').toBuffer();
        overlayResp = await s3.putObject({
            Bucket: IMAGE_BUCKET,
            Body: overlayImg,
            Key: `${filename.replace('original', 'overlay')}`
        }).promise();

    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Overlay err :>> ', err);  //TODO: DLQ
    }
```

I've tried including the image in the 'logos' folder alongside my processNewImage.js folder like so:
[image: filestructure]

Using the above code.  It errors out saying 'Input file is missing'.

I've tried an to import the image `const WHITE = require('/logos/white.png');` and changing the composite line to `.composite([{input: WHITE, gravity: 'southeast' }])` and the result is that the code doesn't even run (`Cannot find module '/logos/white.png`).

It feels like the lambda package doesn't have the image included.  How can I include it and/or make a reference to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path you are using (`/logos/white.png`) is an absolute path and that means that your code is "looking" in the wrong place.

I am not 100% sure but one of the following two options should solve your issue:

1. Use a relative path (`./logos/white.png`)
2. Use the `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT` environment variable:

```
let path = `${process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/logos/white.png`
```

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime

Another option is split the application code and the assets like the image up. The image would go into a Lambda layer which you would be able find in another directory on the Lambdas disk:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path

Comment: The problem came down to serverless including the entire folder structure of the project... it it wasn't ./logos ...  it was ./lambdas/processNewImage/logos....

Thanks!